# How to stop adding a number when it reaches its limit

Tags: php

```
<?php
    session_start();


        if(isset($_POST['sessionNum'])){
            //Declare my counter for the first time

            $_SESSION['initial_count'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
            $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];

    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionCount'])){
         $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
         $_SESSION['sessionCount']++;
    }

$sessionMinus =  $_SESSION['sessionCount'];


?>
```

How do I get it so that if `$_SESSION['sessionCount']` is less than `$_SESSION['sessionNum'],` then add 1 to `$_SESSION['sessionCount']` and if it equals `$_SESSION['sessionNum']`, then stop adding 1 to `$_SESSION['sessionCount']`?

Also if I go back on a previous page and I go back onto this page, I want `$sessionMinus` to go back to '1', and finally if the user refreshes the page, then whatever number `$sessionMinus` is, keep it on that number when page refreshes.

Comment: What have you tried? Sounds like you just need to add some more `if` statements.

Comment: This must be the 5th or 6th question you have asked on the very same subject - ive seen the code `$_SESSION['sessionNum']` lots today ... maybe its time to start reading a [PHP tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php) ... so you actually understand the code in your application

Comment: I have ordered a book on PHP which is coming in a couple of days actually. I am new to php so I don't understand it yet but when I get the book then hopefully I can teach myself :)

Comment: actually you dont really need a book to get the basics of php, it all over the internets

Comment: Yeah but I like to follow a book and learn it step by step and create some php through examples so I can learn it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get it so that if $_SESSION['sessionCount'] is less than
>   $_SESSION['sessionNum'], then add 1 to $_SESSION['sessionCount'] and
>   if it equals $_SESSION['sessionNum'], then stop adding 1 to
>   $_SESSION['sessionCount']?

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['sessionCount'])) {
    $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 1;
}
else if ($_SESSION['sessionCount'] < $_SESSION['sessionNum']) {
    ++$_SESSION['sessionCount'];
}
```

> Also if I go back on a previous page and I go back onto this page, I
>   want $sessionMinus to go back to '1'

To do that you have to set `$_SESSION['sessionMinus']` (or some other variable) in the previous page. Once *this* page is reached, the only way to know what happened earlier is specifically through `$_SESSION` variables. You cannot detect it on the spot.

> and finally if the user
>   refreshes the page, then whatever number $sessionMinus is, keep it on
>   that number when page refreshes.

This is not possible. You cannot tell if the page was refreshed or loaded from scratch¹. What you could do is use the [PRG pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) and count the "P" page as "the user just got here" and the "G" page as "the user has refreshed the page". You can set a variable (e.g. `$_SESSION['redirecting'] = true`) from the "P" page and modify it on the "G" page (`$_SESSION['redirecting'] = false`); just before you do that, check if it was `true` to begin with. If it was, then the user is here due to your redirect (which will only happen once). If it was already `false`, they have refreshed the page.

---

¹You can *try* to do it, again through `$_SESSION`, but really you are just guessing. There is no way to know for certain.

Comment: Could it work if I use a submit button and if I say if(isset('submit')) then add 1, else if it not (lets say page refresh) then do not add a number so number remains the same?

Comment: @user1292857: The page refresh will also include the submit value. As I said, it's not possible to do it directly.

Comment: Ok then, 1 final question, to try and get $sessionMinus on Current page to go back to 1 if user goes on to previous page then back to current page, I have put       if `(!isset($_SESSION['sessionCount'])) {
    $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 1;
}` in previous page so current page goes back to being 1 but this doesn't work, what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_SESSION['sessionCount'] < $_SESSION['sessionNum']) { 
    // sessionNum is bigger then sessionCount
    $_SESSION['sessionCount']++; 
}
```